# Fetch command returning error when making a request to localhost in React-Native framework

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, react-native

I am trying to use fetch to sign up new users to a React Native app I'm making with a POST request to a flask server I've setup and am running locally. This is the code to process the request:

```
async function signUpUser(name, pass) {
    let response = await fetch(
        'http://localhost:5000/api/users/signup', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ username: name, password: pass})
        }
    ).catch(e => {
            console.log('There has been a problem with fetch operation: '
                + e.message)
            throw e;
    });

    response = await response.json();
    handleResponse(response);
}

function handleResponse(JSONResponse) {
    console.log(JSONResponse)
}
```

Right now the response handler is not set up because I'm running into the issue that when I make this request, I get an error "Network request failed". This request works when I try it on Postman and I have no problem making HTTP requests to other sites (for instance `fetch('http://www.google.com/')` does not return this error). I have also included the security config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

in appManifest.xml in an attempt to allow HTTP requests if that was the issue. Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Comment: you are making a request call from your device and for the device, localhost:5000 means nothing and hence `Network request failed`. 

However, you could try a few things like changing,

1. localhost to 127.0.0.1

2. Easiest way is to expose your APIs through `ngrok` HTTP tunnel. All you have to do is run `npx ngrok http 5000` and it will return you a URL exposed to public internet and anyone from your team can use that URL including your React-native app.

Also note, ngrok URL is only valid as long as your computer is turned on and you are running the program.

Comment: I will try the command line solution, but I forgot to mention in my post that calling the IP address localhost vs 127.0.0.1 does not make a difference for me.